# Can you display events in a monthly calendar using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, calendar, pivot

I have a table with events (dates and descriptions).
I want to display the coming events in a calendar format of the current month.
What is the best way to display current events in calendar format using SQL?
I'm targeting Oracle, but maybe there are solutions that are more universal than others.

The output should look similar to this one:

```
     WEEK | MON               | TUE       ! WED       | THU             | FRI       | SAT       | SUN      
--------- ------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
       36 |                   | 01        | 02        | 03 stay at home | 04        | 05        | 06       
       37 | 07                | 08        | 09        | 10              | 11        | 12        | 13       
       38 | 14 work from home | 15        | 16        | 17              | 18        | 19        | 20       
       39 | 21                | 22        | 23        | 24              | 25        | 26        | 27       
       40 | 28                | 29        | 30        |                 |           |           |
```

Comment: Does your source data have an entry for every day, or do you need the report to fill in the blanks? Can there be more than one event per day?

Comment: Good questions @WilliamRobertson, the report will fill in the blanks, but it would be nice to be able to have multiple events per day, so I guess a listagg is in order.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data (including a day with two events):

```
create table calendar
( cal_date   date
, cal_event  varchar2(50) );

insert all
    into calendar values (date '2020-09-03', 'stay at home')
    into calendar values (date '2020-09-03', 'play Fallout')
    into calendar values (date '2020-09-14', 'work from home')
select * from dual;
```

Report:

```
select cal_week as week
     , mon_events as mon
     , tue_events as tue
     , wed_events as wed
     , thu_events as thu
     , fri_events as fri
from   ( select to_char(d.dt,'Dy') as cal_day
               , to_number(to_char(d.dt,'iw')) as cal_week
               , to_char(d.dt,'DD')||' '||listagg(cal_event,', ') within group (order by c.cal_date) as cal_event
         from    ( select date '2020-09-01' -1 + rownum as dt
                   from   xmltable('1 to 30' ) ) d
                 left join calendar c on c.cal_date = d.dt
         group by d.dt
       )
pivot  (max(cal_event) as events
        for (cal_day) in ('Mon' as mon, 'Tue' as tue, 'Wed' as wed, 'Thu' as thu, 'Fri' as fri))
order by cal_week;
```

Results:

```
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-----+
| WEEK | MON               | TUE | WED | THU                           | FRI |
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-----+
|   36 |                   | 01  | 02  | 03 play Fallout, stay at home | 04  |
|   37 | 07                | 08  | 09  | 10                            | 11  |
|   38 | 14 work from home | 15  | 16  | 17                            | 18  |
|   39 | 21                | 22  | 23  | 24                            | 25  |
|   40 | 28                | 29  | 30  |                               |     |
+------+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-----+
```

I had to concatenate the day number with the event list before the `pivot`, which meant the aggregation had to be in the subquery and the `max(cal_event)` is just to satisfy the `pivot` syntax which requires an aggregate function.

Comment: Wow, @William, ,this looks great! I think I prefer the more generic way to generate all days from the current month, but the xmltable function and the pivot ar nice tricks! And I didn't know of insert all ... select * from dual! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This technique( `xmltable('1 to 30' )` ) is really great Mr. Robertson !

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this solution. Maybe someone will be helped by it, but I'm also curious for other solutions.

Edited to include multiple events on the same day.

```
with events as (
  select date'2020-09-03' as dy
  ,      'stay at home' as event
  from dual
  union all
  select date'2020-09-03' as dy
  ,      'stay at home 2' as event
  from dual
  union all
  select date'2020-09-14' as dy
  ,      'work from home' as event
  from dual
    union all
  select date'2020-10-14' as dy
  ,      'work from home' as event
  from dual
) , 
day_events as (
  select dy, listagg(event,', ') within group  (order by event) as event
  from events
  group by dy
)
, month(dy) as (
select trunc(sysdate, 'month') as dy from dual
union all
select dy + 1 from month
where dy < last_day(sysdate)-1
)
, days as (
  select to_char(dy, 'iw') as week,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'mon' then dy end as mon,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'tue' then dy end as tue,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'wed' then dy end as wed,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'thu' then dy end as thu,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'fri' then dy end as fri,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'sat' then dy end as sat,
  case to_char(dy, 'dy') when 'sun' then dy end as sun
  from month
), calendar as (
select week
,      max(mon) as mon
,      max(tue) as tue
,      max(wed) as wed
,      max(thu) as thu
,      max(fri) as fri
,      max(sat) as sat
,      max(sun) as sun
from days
group by week
order by week)
select week
, '| '||decode(mon, e.dy, to_char(mon,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(mon, 'dd')) as "| MON"
, '| '||decode(tue, e.dy, to_char(tue,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(tue, 'dd')) as "| TUE"
, '| '||decode(wed, e.dy, to_char(wed,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(wed, 'dd')) as "! WED"
, '| '||decode(thu, e.dy, to_char(thu,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(thu, 'dd')) as "| THU"
, '| '||decode(fri, e.dy, to_char(fri,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(fri, 'dd')) as "| FRI"
, '| '||decode(sat, e.dy, to_char(sat,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(sat, 'dd')) as "| SAT"
, '| '||decode(sun, e.dy, to_char(sun,'dd')||' '||e.event, to_char(sun, 'dd')) as "| SUN"
from calendar c left join day_events e
on c.week = to_char(e.dy, 'iw')
order by c.week;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional Aggregation with `GROUP`ing `BY` week number :

```
WITH events AS
(
  SELECT date'2020-09-03' AS dy, 'stay at home' AS event
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date'2020-09-14' AS dy
  ,      'work FROM home' AS event
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
  SELECT date'2020-10-14' AS dy
  ,      'work FROM home' AS event
    FROM dual
) ,  month(dy) AS (
SELECT trunc(sysdate, 'month') + level - 1 AS dy 
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <=  last_day(sysdate)-trunc(sysdate, 'month') + 1
)
SELECT TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'iw' ) AS week, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'MON' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "MON",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'TUE' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "TUE",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'WED' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "WED",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'THU' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "THU",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'FRI' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "FRI",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'SAT' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "SAT",
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DY' ) = 'SUN' THEN TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'DD ' )||e.event END) AS "SUN"
  FROM month m 
  LEFT JOIN events e
    ON e.dy = m.dy
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR( m.dy, 'iw' )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5f80dccf4fc1c350a627d6f212cc70f2)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @Rabaros, that is  nice way to reduce the complexity!

Comment: By the way, @Barbaros, I think I prefer the with-clause way to generate the days, because connect by level can only be used in Oracle. I don't know if one or the other has a better performance though.

Comment: You're welcome @Marko . Yes, the performance should be tested. Btw, Pivot clause might be used, also.